# What are these special symbols git log shows for gpg-signed commit?

Tags: git, gnupg

I'm playing around with gpg-signed commits and I'm puzzled by this `^M` that I see in `git log --show-signature`:

```
commit 2ca6e05a384aa8c1c92e4171eca7fa67aa2a2621 (HEAD -> master)
gpg: Signature made 02/19/18 02:38:28 TZ 2 Standard Time^M
gpg:                using RSA key 7BD2AAD0D220147A0FDFC8528570E09FBB1^M
gpg: Good signature from "amomum" [ultimate]^M
```

or with `--pretty=format'%GS'`- it adds `^M` after name of the signer.

What are these `^M`? I thought these are line-ending symbols `\r` but what are they doing there? How can I get rid of them?

I'm using git for windows and gpg4win.

UPD: I believe this is related https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1249

Comment: They are in fact a visual representation of carriage returns, and they probably shouldn't be shown here. I don't use Windows and don't know off hand what to do to make them go away.

Answer (score 2):

Try making a new signed commit after typing:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

And see if the issue persists.
`^M` is crlf instead of lf, and could be the result of an automatic conversion.

The OP mentions [git-for-windows/git issue 1249](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1249): Support for external `gpg2`, corrupted encoding.

I confirm gpg is still 1.x with the latest Git:

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 C:\
> where gpg
D:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin\gpg.exe
> gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.22
```

A [patch is proposed](https://public-inbox.org/git/20171111160657.11016-1-jerzy.kozera@gmail.com/T/#u) to strip CR chars for Windows gpg2, but not yet integrated to Git.

Comment: Unfortunately, autocrlf didn't change anything